# Localizing Google App Engine application with i18n and compilemessage command

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, internationalization

I have an app in Google App Engine. I'm using Python 2.7 with Django 1.4. My `app.yaml`:

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: django
  version: latest

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: myapp.app
```

I'd like to apply internationalization to my app but not exactly sure how... Is there some article or tutorial about this particular thing? I tried to use few different `compile-messages.py` files and tried to run them with `dev_appserver.py compile-messages.py myapp` but all I get is mostly `dev_appserver.py` help page which really doesn't explain anything about localization/internationalization in the project... I'm struggling with searching Google about this thing for almost whole day without some luck :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at webabb2 extras i18n : http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/i18n.html#api-webapp2-extras-i18n

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've also read [this](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/gettingstarted/templates.html) and [this](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/i18n.html) so I'm wondering now, should I rewrite most of my app to use webapp request handlers instead of Django's default ones? Sorry if I got this wrong, I never used webapp2 before... What I need here is really just "simple" translation of strings in my templates...

Comment: I advise to use webapp2, python27 en jinja2. Because Django App engine templating (from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template) is depricated.

Comment: He is a google article to start with these libs: http://blog.notdot.net/2011/11/Migrating-to-Python-2-7-part-2-Webapp-and-templates

Comment: Ah thanks a lot for helping, I already started to read about webapp2... The problem is that my django app was almost completed... Now I have to rewrite most of the stuff here which doesn't seem so simple... Especially since I really never used webapp at all...